# I dont understand why im getting this error in php Array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, forms, cookies, setcookie

Heres whats going on, I want to make a multilingual websites  Array to string conversion error:Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\choose language\language.php on line 12

```
<form action="language_switcher.php" method="post">
<select name="lang">
    <option value="en"<?php if( $_COOKIE["language"] == "en" ) { echo " selected"; } ?>>English</option>
    <option value="fr"<?php if( $_COOKIE["language"] == "fr" ) { echo " selected"; } ?>>Français</option>
    <option value="de"<?php if( $_COOKIE["language"] == "de" ) { echo " selected"; } ?>>Deutsch</option>
    <option value="it"<?php if( $_COOKIE["language"] == "it" ) { echo " selected"; } ?>>Italiano</option>

</select>
<input type="submit" value="Select Language">
</form>

<p>Language: <?php if( isset( $_COOKIE['language'] ) ) { echo $_COOKIE['language']; } else { echo "<em>not set</em>"; } ?></p>
```

Comment: `print_r($_COOKIE['language']);`

Comment: That's a notice, which is a pretty light level of error message. Does this produce the HTML you expect? What do you see when you do var_dump($_COOKIE);?

Answer (score 0):

most likely your

```
$_COOKIE["language"]
```

is NOT a string like "en" but rather an array like array($code=>"en", $name=>"english").  you need to inspect that value first. echo it, print_r it or var_dump it.

add

```
<?php var_dump($_COOKIE["language"]); ?>
```

to the top of your page or anywhere.

Comment: So how would I put that? Sorry, i'm not very familiar with it yet